# vlookup in for lookp with vba

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

i want to compare a list of names against a second list of names with the use of a for loop and vlookup in vba. in other words, if a name is on my list and on the second list, i want to label this entry "counterparty" and all other names as "client".

As soon as a name on my list is not on the second list, the code yields an error "Run-time error 13" when i would want the name to be categorized as a client.

```
Sub final_row1()
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To 10
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, 2), Range("f2:g8"), 1, False) Then
          Cells(i, 3).Value = "counterparty"
        Else
          Cells(i, 3).Value = "client"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub final_row1()
Dim i As Integer
Dim notFound As Boolean

    For i = 2 To 10
        notFound = Application.IsError(Application.VLookup(Cells(i, 2), Range("F2:G8"), 1, False))
        If notFound = False Then
            Cells(i, 3).Value = "counterparty"
        Else
            Cells(i, 3).Value = "client"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the piece of code below, I am using `Application.VLookup` in order to trap the errors.

```
Sub final_row1()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To 10    
        ' a match found between both lists    
        If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(Cells(i, 2), Range("F2:G8"), 1, False)) Then
            Cells(i, 3).Value = "counterparty"
        Else
            Cells(i, 3).Value = "client"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```